# Which Java data type corresponds to postgresql "time without zone"

Tags: java, postgresql

I thought it was `java.sql.Time` but several methods within this class are deprecated. It has only one constructor that receives a long data type argument, just like this.

```
Time(long time)
```

I get from the user a string with the following format: `hh:mm`

Any advices on how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at

```
java.time.LocalTime
```

added in `Java8`

Comment: if only you all knew how people did this in Java 1.2 :-)